# Excel - Sum/Count of boolean values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I am creating a simple scorecard for my Football Pool. Each week a player makes a prediction and the correct guess is in the bottom row.

This is a simplified version of it

| Name | Week1 | Week2 | Week3 |  | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lee | BUF | LAR | TB |  | 3 |
| Beth | BUF | SEA | TB |  | 2 |
| Rick | TEN | LAR | TB |  | 2 |
| Fred | TEN | LAR | PIT |  | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Winner** | **BUF** | **LAR** | **TB** |  |  |

My question is about keeping score. To compute the total in Column F I am currently adding the booleans manually:

```
=(B2=B$7)+(C2=C$7)+(D2=D$7)
```

This is fine for only three columns of course, but it will definitely get quite cumbersome if there are dozens (or more) columns.

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to accomplish this with a formula such as SUM() or SUMIFS() or COUNTIFS() etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!  :)

Comment: Creating a good reprex will enhance your chances to receive appropriate help from the community: look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:D2=$B$7:$D$7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was going to be something simple like that, I just didn't know the proper formula.  

And I never would have though of the double-dash... what does that do?

Comment: @DKLA - they're the [double unary](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary).

Comment: Just an FYI for all -- I also added conditional formatting to the sheet so correct predictions get highlighted. For the range, just add a condition where cells contain the Specific Text of:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(7,COLUMN()))`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DKLA - you should use `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT`. `INDIRECT` is volatile and should be used sparingly.